# Validating Indian phonenumber in windows form application using .net c#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, validation

I am developing a windows form application in .net c#, All I want to know is how to validate the Indian phone number, if a user inputs in a textbox.

Comment: you didn't specify how this phone format is, and didn't write c# in the tags. the question is too vague.

Comment: @vulkanino, see there I wrote c# in the question.

Comment: hook up to a modem and dial the number.... only kidding, what do you want to validate? that the format is correct - do you want to include extenstions, country code etc, you need to be a bit more specific

Comment: @dice, including country code only

Comment: @dice  for example: the text box should accept the number like this (+919821808807).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of Regular expression 
e.g.

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"^((\+){0,1}91(\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}){0,1}9[0-9](\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7}$");
```

and than you can use rx.IsMatch to validate the input string.

Comment: And if you have string with the value "+31(0)12-1234567". This is a correct notation of a phone number. How could you validate with Regex? I have tried this: phonePattern = new Regex(@"\+\d{3}?\(\0\)\d*\-\d*"); What do I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

the standard format of Indian mobile phone number is +91 (country code) followed by 10 digits.

```
+91 XXXXXXXXXX
```

just check if this is followed. if its a land phone number the check is difficult. oryou might get external websites which can validate the number for you.

All you can do is check for the country code for an exact match. then the rest are all digits and there is 10 of them. no other characters allowed. In india we dont we dont use - to separate between digits

Comment: Yea! That was an awesome solution!

Comment: thanks! and if you are sure of the country then why not hard code +91?

Comment: There are easier ways like limiting the text box characters to 10 etc. Check out any of the regular expressions meant for phone number validation

Comment: sure thing now, It was a very helpfull of you. I am now working on ur given solution.

Answer (score 1):

In c# you need a regex that checks for +91 followed by 10 digits

it may also be worth checking for 0091 followed by 10 digits

**EDIT**
just for completeness sake the following would do `(\+91|0091)\d{10}`

Answer (score 1):

System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex expr;

```
    public bool email(string email)
    {
        expr =new  Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z][\w\.-]{2,28}[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]$");
        if (expr.IsMatch(email))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
    public bool phone(string no)
    {
        expr = new Regex(@"^((\+){0,1}91(\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}){0,1}9[0-9](\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7}$");
        if (expr.IsMatch(no))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried all above mentioned methods, didn't worked out for Me... So I made own Code:-

### It will work for SURE:

```
private void btnValidatePhoneNumber_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Regex re = new Regex("^9[0-9]{9}");

        if(re.IsMatch(txtPhone.Text.Trim()) == false || txtPhone.Text.Length>10)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Indian Mobile Number!!");
            txtPhone.Focus();
        }

    }
```

*upvote if you like it!* :)